# Proof Big O/Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, induction, recurrence-relations

In a combinatorics book, in recursion/induction chapter, there is an exercise that says:

Let $f(n)$ be a number sequence such that $f(2n) ≤ 2f(n)+2n$, $f(1) = 0$, $f(2) = 1$.

Show that $f(n) ≤ 10^{100}n\log_2 n$ cannot be true in general.

for proving is there a counter example we can come up with? How can we go about finding it?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you name the book and author?

Comment: @lulu, the first one. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have edited accordingly.  You can click on "Edit" to see the syntax I used.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I included an image of the whole question for your reference.

Comment: I know part 1, I don't know how to start part 2 and 3.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 2, $f$ and the given values only fix $f$ for powers of $2$. In particular $f(3)$ or $f(1337)$ may be any number we like so as to violate $f(n)\le10^{100}\log n$.

Now we assume $f$ is increasing for part 3 and suppose $f(n)>k2^k$. Then $f(2^k)\ge f(n)>k2^k$ as well, which is a contradiction, so $f(n)\le k2^k$. Then from $2^{k-1}<n$ and $\log n\ge1$ for $n\ge2$ we get
$$2^k<2n\qquad k<1+\log n$$
$$f(n)\le k2^k<2n(1+\log n)\le2n(2\log n)=4n\log n$$

Comment: Beautiful proof. Thank you so much! You are great.